# Cross reference data between two entities in Master Data Service (MDS)

Tags: master-data-services, mds

I am doing a POC in MDS wherein i have two tables in two different systems like below:

```
A   |  B  | C
----|-----|----
A1  |  B1 | C1
A2  |  B2 | C2
A3  |  B3 | C3
```

and

```
X   |  Y  | Z
----|-----|----
X1  |  Y1 | Z1
X2  |  Y2 | Z2
X3  |  Y3 | Z3
```

These tables are cross referenced as 
*A is equivalent to X*
*B is equivalent to Y*
*C is equivalent to Z*

I have to establish this cross reference in MDS wherein, i the changes made in entity ABC are automatically reflected in entity XYZ.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What logically defines a change?  If I change one column value, should the corresponding column change?  More important, how would we join these two tables together?

Comment: Yes Tim. If i add a row to ABC,a corresponding record should be updated in XYZ. For joining, we can have a primary key, lets say ID.

Comment: Are you concerned with _inserting_ or _updating_, or both?  If you just want to write to both tables you could use an after insert trigger which does that.

Comment: Both. Both these tables would be in different environments (database servers), what i would want is to create entities in MDS, update those entities in MDS with cross reference and then publish the modified entities to respective DBs

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MDS 2016, i think it can be achieved through Entity Sync relationship.

Comment: I am using MDS 2014. Is there i way to achieve it in 2014?